# How to Record Variables in Pytorch Without Breaking Gradient Computation?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, reward

I am trying to implement some policy gradient training, similar to [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#pathwise-derivative). However, I would like to manipulate the rewards(like discounted future sum and other differentiable operations) before doing the backward propagation.

Consider the `manipulate` function defined to calculate the [reward to go](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html#implementing-reward-to-go-policy-gradient):

```
def manipulate(reward_pool):
    n = len(reward_pool)
    R = np.zeros_like(reward_pool)
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        R[i] = reward_pool[i] + (R[i+1] if i+1 < n else 0)
    return T.as_tensor(R)
```

I tried to store the rewards in a list:

```
#pseudocode
reward_pool = [0 for i in range(batch_size)]

for k in batch_size:
  act = net(state)
  state, reward = env.step(act)
  reward_pool[k] = reward

R = manipulate(reward_pool)
R.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

It seems like inplace operation breaks the gradient computation, the code gives me an error: `one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation`.

I also tried to initialize an empty tensor first, and store it in the tensor, but inplace operation is still the issue - `a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.`

I am kind of new to PyTorch. Does anyone know what the right way recording rewards is in this case?

Comment: Please provide your manipulate function.

Comment: @joe32140 I added a sample manipulate function to calculate the reward to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to assignment to existing object.
Simply initialize the empty pool(list) for each iteration and append to the pool when new reward is calculated, i.e.

```
reward_pool = []

for k in batch_size:
  act = net(state)
  state, reward = env.step(act)
  reward_pool.append(reward)

R = manipulate(reward_pool)
R.backward()
optimizer.step()
```